# How to install and run openni_tracker for Hydro

Tags: kinect, skeleton-tracker, ros-hydro, ubuntu, ubuntu-precise

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you in advance for your help and patience.  I am new to ROS  and could use some help with openni_tracker and the Microsoft Kinect.  I'm am using Ubuntu 12.04 and ROS Hydro

I have installed openni_camera and openni_launch according to [openni_camera](http://wiki.ros.org/openni_camera):

```
$ sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-openni-camera
$ sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-openni-launch
$ rosdep update
```

I have no problems running [openni_launch](http://wiki.ros.org/openni_launch) and viewing the point cloud data, color image, or disparity view using Rviz and image_view.

I have installed [openni_tracker](http://wiki.ros.org/openni_tracker):

```
$ sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-openni-tracker
$ rosdep update
$ roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch
$ rosrun openni_tracker openni_tracker
```

and get an error

```
[ERROR] [1416949546.535139208]: Find user generator failed: This operation is invalid!
```

I've uninstalled ROS (both Groovy and Hydro) with

```
$ sudo apt-get remove ros-<distro>
```

and still the problem comes up.  I've read in a few threads that I should install NITE dev or something to help.  But have also noticed that it hasn't helped some people.

Again, I am new to this, so some step-by-step help would be much appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**
I've also installed openni2_tracker...located in ~/catkin_ws/src/.  When I go back to my catkin_ws and use catkin_make, I get the following errors:

```
-- ==> add_subdirectory(openni2_tracker)
CMake Error at /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package orocos_kdl.

  Set orocos_kdl_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration file
  for orocos_kdl.  The file will have one of the following names:

    orocos_kdlConfig.cmake
    orocos_kdl-config.cmake

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  openni2_tracker/CMakeLists.txt:3 (find_package)


-- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
-- /usr/lib/libOpenNI2.so
status
status
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
Nite2_INCLUDEDIR
   used as include directory in directory /home/ecejames01/catkin_ws/src/openni2_tracker
Nite2_LIBRARY
    linked by target "openni2_tracker" in directory /home/ecejames01/catkin_ws/src/openni2_tracker

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

I am not sure what this means or how to fix the problem...thanks for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198495/how-to-install-and-run-openni_tracker-for-hydro/) by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) on ROS Answers with karma: 323 on 2014-11-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have found the solution to my issue on [this page](https://github.com/ros-drivers/openni_tracker/issues/5) and [this page](http://answers.ros.org/question/42654/openninite-incompatible-in-fuertegroovy-on-precise/).

And was able to successfully view the tf for all my 'joints' via Rviz using [this page](http://answers.ros.org/question/55827/openni_tracker-displaying-pointcloud-and-skeleton-alignment/).

Thanks.

---

Originally posted by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) with karma: 323 on 2014-11-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0